# What is the meaning of "encourages it for… on" in this context?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

> Agriculture expands yield production to meet demand to limit overlapping, and the government **encourages it for crop yield forecast on TamilNadu dataset imports.**"

What does "encourages it for… on" mean in the above context?

Comment: It's a very poorly written sentence, with multiple stacked/tricky premodifiers and what I take to be a chained of to-infinitive clauses showing reason (to do A to do B). One assumes that 'Agriculture' means 'those involved in agriculture'.  I'd take, on a fifth reading, the sentence to mean: << The concerns managing agriculture expand yield production to meet demand, but in such a way as to limit overlapping. The government encourages _such an expansion to be initiated_ in response to the crop yield forecast on TamilNadu dataset imports. >> But it's a guess.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your explanation